# Can we give the space between two controls in a stackpanel in WPF?

Tags: wpf

Can we give the space between two controls in a stackpanel in WPF?

Comment: shouldn't margin do the trick?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Margin` property on the controls that sit in the StackPanel.